# Annotating gracefully pandas plot with texts that do not overlap

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I have the below pandas dataframe containing some events and a count that i'm looking to plot and annotate with event details in the chart:

```
Date    Time    Time Zone   Currency    Event   Importance  Actual  Forecast    Previous    Count   Volume
DateTime                                            
2014-04-09 00:30:00  Wed Apr 9   00:30   GMT     aud     AUD Westpac Consumer Confidence     Medium  0.3%    NaN     -0.7%   198     7739
2014-04-09 00:30:00  Wed Apr 9   00:30   GMT     aud     AUD Westpac Consumer Conf Index     Low     99.7    NaN     99.5    198     7279
2014-04-09 01:30:00  Wed Apr 9   01:30   GMT     aud     AUD Investment Lending  Low     4.4%    NaN     -3.7%   172     21297
2014-04-09 01:30:00  Wed Apr 9   01:30   GMT     aud     AUD Home Loans  Medium  2.3%    1.5%    0.0%    172     22197
2014-04-09 01:30:00  Wed Apr 9   01:30   GMT     aud     AUD Value of Loans (MoM)    Low     1.9%    NaN     1.6%    172     22197
```

I'm using the below code to plot the dataframe (df):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

temp=df[df['Count'].notnull()]
#temp=temp[temp['Importance']=="High"]

x = temp.index
y = temp.Count
z = temp.Event
g = temp.Importance
v = temp.Volume

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
ax.plot_date(x, y, linestyle='--')

for i in range(len(x)):
    if g[i]=="Medium":
        ax.annotate(z[i]+' '+'Volume: '+str(v[i]), (mdates.date2num(x[i]), y[i]), xytext=(15, 15), 
            textcoords='offset points', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'))


fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

As the dataframe contains duplicate - datetime - indexes, the annotated text is coming up in a overlapped fashion:

[image: overlappinglabels]

Is there a better way of displaying this?

Possible solution: 
Think I managed to get an ok plot by randomising the xytext values

```
ax.annotate(z[i]+' '+'Volume: '+str(v[i]), (mdates.date2num(x[i]), y[i]), xytext=(5+randint(1,50), 5+randint(1,50)), 
            textcoords='offset points', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'), rotation=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can solve the overlapping annotation by rotating the annotation text. This can be done by adding 'rotation=90'

```
ax.annotate(z[i]+' '+'Volume: '+str(v[i]), (mdates.date2num(x[i]), y[i]), xytext=(15, 15), 
            textcoords='offset points', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'), rotation=90)
```

Comment: Doesnt look like it takes away the issue of overalapping text especially if you are using static values for rotation. Even with random values it doesn't look too good: `ax.annotate(z[i]+' '+'Volume: '+str(v[i]), (mdates.date2num(x[i]), y[i]), xytext=(1, 1), 
            textcoords='offset points', arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>'), rotation=randint(4.5,9)*10)`